# Vim - surround multiple lines in <p> tag

Tags: vim

How do I get from this:

```
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
```

to this:

```
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
<p>hello world</p>
```

using vim-surround or vim-emmet.

When I highlight the text, press ctrl+y and then ',' I can type p tag however it surrounds all 4 paragraphs in one p tag.

Comment: You what, mate? @SergioAraujo

Comment: Sorry if I wouldn't get my message through @jedi

Answer (score 8):

### With Surround:

```
vjjj                " select the block (or whatever works for your actual use case)
:norm yss<p><CR>    " execute the normal mode yss command provided by Surround
                    " on each line of the selection
                    " note that Vim automatically inserts the range corresponding
                    " to your visual selection: :'<,'>norm ...
```

Or if you are confident with ranges:

```
:,+3norm yss<p><CR>
```

### Without any plugin:

```
C<p><C-r><C-o>"</p><Esc>
j0.
j0.
j0.
```

Or a variant:

```
C<p><C-r><C-o>"</p><Esc>
jvjj
:'<,'>norm .
```

Or a variant of the variant above if you are confident with ranges:

```
C<p><C-r><C-o>"</p><Esc>
:+,+2norm .
```

Or a single step variant of the three variants above:

```
:,+3norm C<p><C-v><C-r><C-v><C-o>"</p><CR>
```

Or a completely different method, using a super simple substitution:

```
:,+3s@.*@<p>&</p><CR>
```

### Reference:

```
:help C
:help ctrl-r_ctrl-o
:help registers
:help .
:help :normal
:help :range
:help :s
```

Comment: You can also use surround.vim + visual block. e.g. `<c-v>jjj$S<p>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the multiple select command on the hello world

```
gb
```

and then just use

```
S<p>
```